# why do I keep getting null exceptions at setOnClickListener

Tags: android

Why do I kee[ getting null errors at setOnClickListener?
R.layout.dataentry is the ContentView.  It has the addRecord (a button) and it loads and displays fine.
It looks as though R.id.addRecord gets an ID when I look in the debugger).
I'm sure it has something to do with the ContentView not being loaded correctly resulting in a null pointer exception when I try to add the listenter, but I've tried preloading it several ways (here, earlier) and I can't figure out how to do it.  I guess I'd prefer to have all my views cached so that I can add listeners early.  Can someone help?

Thanks.

```
      exercise = (RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.exerciseType);
         addRecord = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.addRecord);
         amount = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.amount);
         datePerformed = (DatePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.datePerfomed);

public void loadAddEntry() {
            setContentView(R.layout.dataentry);
            addRecord.setOnClickListener(
                 new View.OnClickListener(){
                     public void onClick(View view) {
                         addRecordClicked();
                    }

                    ;});

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way... you have something like:

```
exercise = (RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.exerciseType);
```

Which I guess is on the `onCreate` method, and previous to those lines you should have another `setContentView(R.layout.anotherstuff);`. Then, you have a `loadAddEntry` method with `setContentView(R.layout.dataentry);`. So, here you have a problem: if you have already defined another contentview, why are you redefining it?

Comment: I am redefining it because it is a second form.  The first is a login form, then I want to use "add an entry" form. The first one loads ok, submits ok, etc.  The second one loads ok, until I add the part about the ClickListener.  There doesn't seem to be an issue with the way it is being created, unless there is something I don't understand.  Am I supposed to be doing this differently?

Comment: You mean those are on different activities? Can you please paste the whole activities code?

Comment: They are on the same activity for simplicity. I put in all my code.

Comment: What is comes down to is that I needed to step in line and make each form its own activity.

Comment: Well... so that's what is wrong. You cannot be switching the ContentView whenever you want. If you have an external layout and want to use it, you have to inflate it (using the `LayoutInflater`). Google is your friend in this case.